# что такое android N и как его будет поддерживать Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Сейчас устанавливаю Studio 2.1 и читая описание понял, что одним из преимуществ является то, что она может работать с android N. В котором можно применять принципы Java8... Как то так я понял

1. Почитал про android N и не понял это версия 7.0 после `Marshmallow`
   ?
2. Новая 2.1 полностью совместима с предыдущими версиями? Не получиться
   так, что эта версия только для android N?
3. И насчет канала обнослений посоветуйте какой нужно использовать?
   Согласно офф. документации написано, что уже доступны обновления
   `Canary channel`

> Предварительная версия Android Studio 2.1 в настоящее время доступна на канале обновлений Canary.

У меня сейчас студия обновляется по `Stable channel` я почитал про `Canary` и написано, что она не рекомендуется...

Comment: 1. да, 2. все путем, 3. stable channel логично лучше)

Comment: Android N - это будет API24, но [не обязательно версия 7.0](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) - API 5 - 10 были версии 2.x, API 11 - 13 версии 3.x, API 14-19 версии 4.x , API 21-22 - версии 5.x. При этом   API 14, 16 и 19 имели собственные имена - Ice Cream Sandwich, Jelly Bean и KitKat

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Android N` - следующая версия после `Android M`, у которого версия `6.0 (API 23)`. Релиз будет скорее всего осенью, как обычно и происходит - выход "мажорных" обновлений раз в год.

В данный момент выпускаются бета прошивки для Nexus устройств, как раз для разработчиков, с целью теста и перевода своих приложений на новую версию `API` к релизу `Android N`. `API` уже доступно сейчас через `SDK Manager`, можно попробовать новые фишки.

Теперь про `Android Studio 2.1`: у меня, если не ошибаюсь, она обновилась с версии 2.0, которая вышла в апреле, причем на канале обновлений `Stable`.

И API N версии, и студия версии 2.1 полностью обратно совместимы с предыдущими версиями API.

Канал обновления лучше выбирать `Stable`, как понятно из названия - стабильный. Далее идут каналы `Beta`, `Dev` и `Canary`, где `Canary` является самым нестабильным.

Comment: Спасибо! Именно то что я хотел уточнить